# How to read strings separated by return from a file

Tags: java, algorithm, file, sorting, java.util.scanner

My task is to re-alphabetize a dictionary using 5 different sorting algorithms. I have the algorithms taken care of. The thing I am having trouble with is being able to read a string of text from a file and stop where the definition of the word ends without moving onto the next entry. This means I need each index of my array to be a word and its definition like so:

a[i] = "coronet:   n. inferior crown denoting, according to its form, various degrees of noble rank less than sovereign.";

Where it is taken from a list arranged like so:

//Begin list

"orthogonal:   adj. having or determined by right angles.

deviate:   v. to take a different course.

coronet:   n. inferior crown denoting, according to its form, various degrees of noble rank less than sovereign.

incite:   v. to rouse to a particular action.

deface:   v. to mar or disfigure the face or external surface of."

//End list

From there I can actually sort this array, but I'm currently having trouble using Scanner to properly distinguish where each definition ends.

I have no code for anybody to improve, I just need a method of solving this problem.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: How about `Scanner.nextLine()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but according to your example, each definition begins with a new line. In that case you can use this code to read one line at a time.

```
ArrayList<String> defs = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(*path*));
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
     defs.add(sc.nextLine());
}
```